# Changing Citation Format bib latex (In collection, PhD Thesis)

Tags: biblatex

I am a new LaTeX user. I work with TeXShop for Mac and BibDesk for citations (PhD Thesis). I use the package `biblatex`.

Following the package info I was able to adapt several details of the verbose style to the demands of my Italian Univ. Style Guide. However, several still need to be fixed.

1. For in collection papers, I need this format:

   J. SMITH, "Title", *Book Title*. Subtitle (eds. R.SMITH - M. SMITH) (Series #; Place Date) page number.
2. For PhD Theses, this:

   J. SMITH, *Title* (Diss. University Name; Place Date) page number.
3. I was able to add hyphen between authors of a collective work, but still cannot get rid of commas that are printed right after last name:

   Getting now: J. SMITH, - M. SMITH, etc.

   Need to get: J. SMITH - M. SMITH, *Title* (Series #; Place Date) page number.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose,firstinits=true,isbn=false,url=false,doi=false,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection]{pages}{#1}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}\addspace}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{publisher}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{publisher}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{language}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{edition}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{edition}}
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{\printtext[parens]{\printfield{series}\addspace\printfield{number}\addspace\addsemicolon\addspace\printlist{location}\addspace\setunit*{\addspace}\usebibmacro{date}}\newunit}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\space}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{~--\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{~--\space}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}

@BOOK{brockington_critical_1961,
  title = {A Critical Introduction to the Apocrypha},
  publisher = {Duckworth},
  year = {1961},
  author = {L.H. Brockington},
  address = {London},
  series = {Studies in Theology}
}

@INCOLLECTION{nunlist_naratological_2009,
  author = {René Nünlist},
  title = {Narratological Concepts in the Greek Scholia},
  publisher = {De Gruyter},
  year = {2009},
  editor = {Jonas Grethlein},
  series = {TCSV},
  number = {4},
  pages = {63-83},
  address = {Berlin - New York (NY)}
}

@INCOLLECTION{speyer_divinemessenger_2007,
  author = {Wolfgang Speyer},
  title = {The Divine Messenger in Ancient Greece, Etruria and Rome},
  publisher = {De Gruyter},
  year = {2007},
  editors = {F.V. Reiterer and T. Nicklas and K. Schöpflin},
  series = {DCLY},
  pages = {35-47},
  address = {Berlin - New York (NY)}
}

@ARTICLE{carasik_limits_2000,
  author = {Michael Carasik},
  title = {The Limits of Omniscience},
  journal = {JBL},
  year = {2000},
  volume = {119},
  number = {2},
  pages = {221-232},
}

@PHDTHESIS{broida_forestalling_2013,
  author = {Marian W. Broida},
  title = {Forestalling Doom: «Apotropaic Intercession» in the Hebrew Bible and Ancient Near East},
  school = {Emory University},
  year = {2013},
  address = {Atlanta, GA}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Book\autocite[][]{brockington_critical_1961}\\

Article\autocite[][]{carasik_limits_2000}\\

Incollection\autocite[][]{nunlist_naratological_2009}\\

Incollection\autocite{speyer_divinemessenger_2007}\\ %various editors%

PhD Thesis\autocite[][]{broida_forestalling_2013}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Present Citations Formatting Result]
ADDS:

1. In a collective work with various editors, need to get the abbreviation "eds." this way, after the last editor's name between ().
   J. SMITH - M. SMITH (eds.), *Bla Bla Bla*. Bla Bla Bla (Series #; Address Date).
2. So far, whenever a bib entry did not have series&#, I get an unnecessary space plus the punctuation (;) like this: ( ; Atlanta (GA) 2000). I should have only this: (Atlanta (GA) 2000).
3. ARTICLE: volume-issue separator must be "/" like this: *JBL* 123/2 (2000) 23-33.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Please tell us, what you already adapted, so that we do not have to start from zero. In this post you can find an example, how to compose a minimal working example including bibliographic data: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/36296

Comment: Hello! Just edited my question and added the info required. Thanks!

Comment: You can make our lives a bit easier if you turn your code above into a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that also includes some example `.bib` entries so we don't have to come up with the test cases ourselves (see also [the help on MWEBs](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)).

Comment: Just read info at your link on MWEBs...will try producing it over the weekend. Hope I am capable of doing it...thanks for the attention.

Comment: Any chance of that MWE?

Comment: Still not able to produce the MWE...although could not dedicate much time to it...a bit late with some due work to submit in my PhD...focused very much in that in the moment...thanks for the patience...

Comment: Hi! Just tried presenting a MWE after quite a while...hopefully useful to get some help! Thanks!

Comment: Why are you YELLING?

Comment: Sorry for giving that impression Paul...In any case I am eagerly desiring to submit my dissertation in the first week of February...or thereabouts...for that I need to get my footnotes fixed according to my Uni style guidelines...thanks!